# How to select two atributes of list for a List of int

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want get two atributes int for a List:

I try :

```
            List<int> idsAgrupados = listMain.Select(x => new { x.productID, x.personalID}).Cast<int>().ToList();
```

but this way I get a conversion error.

[image]

Comment: In your Linq, it returns `List of anonymous type` (which it is an object) but you declare your variable as `List<int?>` type. Your variable is expected to receive result of List<int?> type.

Comment: i edited the aswer with Cast, but this way I get a conversion error.

Comment: @YongShun and so i don't know how to do it, i just put what i tried

Comment: Hi @joeyanthon, your update code `Cast` is also will throw casting exception. Can you provide sample input and expected output in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Should be : ((x.productID & 0xFFFF) << 16) | ((x.personalID & 0xFFFF) and make it a uint.

Comment: i updated this post

Comment: You have an IEnumerable of an anonymous object with two variables in it, which you are trying to cast to one IEnumerable of int values.  Clearly that won't work without telling the compiler how to turn two variables into one int.  Do you want the object you made with the two id variables in it as a list?  Do you want to run some operation against the two ids to turn them into one int?

Comment: What is a *two atributes int*?

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like this:**

```
        List<int> firstList = data.Select(x => x.firstId).ToList();
        List<int> secondList = data.Select(x => x.secondId).ToList();

        List<List<int>> g = new List<List<int>>()
        {
            firstList,
            secondList
        };
```

Comment: Where are you casting the selected attribute in integer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all the attributes in select of lambda then convert each item individually.

```
List<int> idsAgrupados = listMain.Select(x => new { productID = Convert.ToInt32(x.productID), personalID = Convert.ToInt32(x.personalID) }).ToList();
```

Let me know if you face any error in this.